# Как сделать плагин комментариев Facebook резиновым?

Tags: facebook, html, javascript, css

У меня адаптивный дизайн, а комментарии можно задать только фиксированной ширины. Я уже не знаю, что делать. ВКонтакте, как ни странно, проблем не доставило.

Answer (score 1):

Жуткий костыль, конечно, зато дешево и сердито.

```
(function(){
  var t=setInterval(function(){//ждем пока не загрузится iframe
    if($('.fb-comments span iframe').length){//если iframe добавился 
      $('.fb-comments span').width('100%');//задаем относительную ширину
      $('.fb-comments span iframe').width('100%');
      clearInterval(t);//заканчиваем
    }
  },
  100)//iframe ищем каждые 100 мс.
 }()
);
```

добавляем width:100% в контейнер:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://blabla.bla" data-num-posts="2" style='width:100%'>
```

Comment: Да, костыль хороший))

Answer (score 0):

Меня спасло просто добавление !important к свойствам:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.fb-comments iframe {
    width: 100%!important;
    margin-left: 0px!important;
    margin-top: 0px!important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

может такой вариант поможет

```
.fb-comments, 
.fb-comments span, 
.fb-comments iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```